# How to install gulp globally in current project?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, system-installation, software-installation, sudo

Trying to install Gulp globally in the project file

```
$ npm install --global gulp

$ npm install --save-dev gulp
```

but got this error message:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/lib/nodejs/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-42-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--global" "gulp"
npm ERR! cwd /home/kanat/Public/mytestpage
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kanat/Public/mytestpage/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Does anybody know how to fix that?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried running it as with sudo?

```
sudo npm install --global gulp
sudo npm install -g gulp
```

The other command is when you try to default gulp file, you should install gulp first.

---

- For gulp command version:

If you have previously installed a version of gulp globally, please run

```
$ npm rm --global gulp
```

to make sure your old version doesn't collide with gulp-cli.

```
$ npm install --global gulp-cli
```

Install gulp in your project devDependencies:

```
$ npm install --save-dev gulp
```

Create a gulpfile.js at the root of your project:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  // place code for your default task here
});
```

Run gulp:

```
$ gulp
```

---

If you have problems running gulp, consider nodejs tries to call it from bad location, so you can add:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Comment: I had solved this . But anyway thanks for response dude

Comment: no worries. Good question, thought.

Comment: @kirgiz_jigit How did you solve your problem?